# Trying to understand what it means to disable a firewall on computer yet maintain firewall on home network?

Tags: networking, router, firewall

I am setting up a web server on a Ubuntu desktop at home via [methods at DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). As part of this I need to allow access to “Apache Full” via `ufw`. I want to make sure that this is not editing my firewall to my home, but just on this computer.

Note that I have a LinkSys router and on my home router webpage it says “IPv4 SPI firewall protection” is enabled (as well as IPv6).

Am I correct in understanding that I have only edited my local computer’s firewall to allow access to Apache from within my home network and that the integrity of my home network’s firewall has not been altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct in understanding that I have only edited my local computer’s firewall to allow access to Apache from within my home network and that the integrity of my home network’s firewall has not been altered?

If you only issued UFW commands on on your server, these only change the firewall settings on that computer and the firewall on your router wasn't changed.

Of course, if you later want to use that server from outside your home, you’ll likely have to change things on your router. But until them you are safe. But given the price of a VPS server(virtual private server) these days, better use an externally hosted server elsewhere when you want do do so.